# Imprimir mais deu uma pagina PrintPageEventArgs C#

Tags: c#

Estou com uma dificuldade para adicionar uma segunda página em diante.... Eu recebo os dados de um DataGrid e na hora de imprimir os dados estão sobrepondo em uma única página...

[Imagem com erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjs5V.jpg)

```
 private void layout_validade(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs Relatorio)
        {
             int LinhaAtual = 0;

          for (int cont = 1; cont <= (dtgrid.NewRowIndex); cont++)
          {
           
            string Qtde = dtgrid.Rows[LinhaAtual].Cells[0].Value.ToString().ToUpper();
            string Lote = dtgrid.Rows[LinhaAtual].Cells[1].Value.ToString().ToUpper();
            string ean_cx = dtgrid.Rows[LinhaAtual].Cells[2].Value.ToString().ToUpper();
            string ean = dtgrid.Rows[LinhaAtual].Cells[3].Value.ToString().ToUpper();
            string Conferente = dtgrid.Rows[LinhaAtual].Cells[4].Value.ToString().ToUpper();
            string Receb = dtgrid.Rows[LinhaAtual].Cells[5].Value.ToString().ToUpper();
            string registro = dtgrid.Rows[LinhaAtual].Cells[6].Value.ToString().ToUpper();
            string Codigo = dtgrid.Rows[LinhaAtual].Cells[7].Value.ToString().ToUpper();
            string Descricao = dtgrid.Rows[LinhaAtual].Cells[8].Value.ToString().ToUpper();
            string validade = dtgrid.Rows[LinhaAtual].Cells[9].Value.ToString().ToUpper();
            string Sequencia = dtgrid.Rows[LinhaAtual].Cells[10].Value.ToString().ToUpper();

            float esquerda = (float)Relatorio.MarginBounds.Left;
            float topo = (float)Relatorio.MarginBounds.Top;
            float direita = (float)Relatorio.MarginBounds.Right;
            float inferior = (float)Relatorio.MarginBounds.Bottom;
            float altura = (float)Relatorio.MarginBounds.Height;
            float linesPerPage = 0;
            String line = null;

          

            Font font_Times_Codigo = new Font("Arial black", 95);
            Font font_Times_Descricao = new Font("Times New Roman", 30f);
            Font font3_Verdana = new Font("Verdana", 22f, FontStyle.Bold);
            Font font4_verdana = new Font("Verdana", 200f, FontStyle.Bold);
            Font font5_timeNewRoman = new Font("Times New Roman", 20f);
            Pen Linha_principal = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(128, 128, 128), 3f);
            Pen Linha_secundaria = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(128, 128, 128), 1f);

            linesPerPage = altura /
            font_Times_Codigo.GetHeight(Relatorio.Graphics);


          Rectangle caixa_codigo = new Rectangle(340, 10, 800, 350);// ESQ , TOP , LARG , COMP  
          Rectangle caixa_imagem = new Rectangle(10, 10, 350, 170);// ESQ , TOP , LARG , COMP
          Relatorio.Graphics.DrawString(Codigo, font_Times_Codigo, Brushes.Black, caixa_codigo, new StringFormat());//Código
          Relatorio.Graphics.DrawString(Descricao, font_Times_Descricao, Brushes.Black, esquerda + 10, topo + 185f, new StringFormat());//Descrição        
  
            if (comboBox_embresa.Text == "GIMBA")
            {
                Relatorio.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.GIMBA, caixa_imagem);
               
            }
            else
            {
              Relatorio.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.IDEIALOG, caixa_imagem);              
            }

            Relatorio.Graphics.DrawLine(Linha_principal, esquerda, 185, direita, 185);//linha acima da descrição
            Relatorio.Graphics.DrawLine(Linha_principal, esquerda, 190, direita, 190); //linha acima da descrição  
            Relatorio.Graphics.DrawLine(Linha_secundaria, esquerda, 244, direita, 244);//linha abaixo da descrição

            Relatorio.Graphics.DrawLine(Linha_principal, esquerda, topo, direita, topo);
            Relatorio.Graphics.DrawLine(Linha_principal, esquerda, topo, esquerda, inferior);
            Relatorio.Graphics.DrawLine(Linha_principal, esquerda, inferior, direita, inferior);
            Relatorio.Graphics.DrawLine(Linha_principal, direita, topo, direita, inferior);
            Relatorio.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Linha_secundaria, esquerda + 0f, 244, 235f, 305);
            Relatorio.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Linha_secundaria, esquerda + 0f, 244, 980, 305);
            Relatorio.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Linha_secundaria, esquerda + 0f, 244, 500, 50);
            Relatorio.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Linha_secundaria, esquerda + 0f, 244, 500, 110);
            Relatorio.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Linha_secundaria, esquerda + 0f, 354, 600, 60);
            Relatorio.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Linha_secundaria, esquerda + 0f, 244, 980, 110);
            Relatorio.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Linha_secundaria, esquerda + 0f, 244, 980, 170);
            Relatorio.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Linha_secundaria, esquerda + 0f, 244, 980, 240);
          

            Relatorio.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(60, 60, 60), 60f), esquerda, topo + 590f, direita, topo + 590f);
            Relatorio.Graphics.DrawString("Validade", new Font("Arial black", 45f), Brushes.White, esquerda + 400, topo + 546f, new StringFormat());
            Relatorio.Graphics.DrawLine(Linha_principal, esquerda, 565, direita, 565);//linha validade
            Relatorio.Graphics.DrawLine(Linha_principal, esquerda, 570, direita, 570);//linha validade     
         
            float dim_65 = 65f;
            float dim_240 = 240f;
            float TOP_1 = 355f;
            float ESQ_1 = 0f;
           // int lista = 0;
            int contador = 1;
          
            for ( int lista = 0; lista <= contador; lista++)
            {  
                for (int index_lista = 0; index_lista <= contador; index_lista++)
                {      
                            if (lista == 0)
                            {
                             Relatorio.Graphics.DrawString(this.tab_lote[index_lista], font3_Verdana, Brushes.Black, esquerda + ESQ_1, TOP_1 - 110, new StringFormat());                         

                            }
                            else
                            {

                                switch (index_lista)
                                {
                                    case 0:
                                        Relatorio.Graphics.DrawString(Qtde, font3_Verdana, Brushes.Black, esquerda + ESQ_1, TOP_1 - 110, new StringFormat());// qtde // lote // re // caixa
                                        break;
                                    case 1:
                                        Relatorio.Graphics.DrawString(Lote, font3_Verdana, Brushes.Black, esquerda + ESQ_1, TOP_1 - 110, new StringFormat());// qtde // lote // re // caixa
                                        break;
                                    case 2:
                                        Relatorio.Graphics.DrawString(ean_cx, font3_Verdana, Brushes.Black, esquerda + ESQ_1, TOP_1 - 110, new StringFormat());// qtde // lote // re // caixa
                                        break;
                                    case 3:
                                        Relatorio.Graphics.DrawString(ean, font3_Verdana, Brushes.Black, esquerda + ESQ_1, TOP_1 - 110, new StringFormat());//UNIDADE
                                        break;
                                    case 4:
                                        Relatorio.Graphics.DrawString(Conferente, font3_Verdana, Brushes.Black, esquerda + ESQ_1, TOP_1 - 105, new StringFormat());                                   
                                        Relatorio.Graphics.DrawString(string.Format("Data{0}Recebimento: ", "\r\n"), font3_Verdana, Brushes.Black, 505, 255, new StringFormat());
                                        Relatorio.Graphics.DrawString(Convert.ToDateTime(Receb).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), font3_Verdana, Brushes.Black, 745, 294, new StringFormat());                                         
                                        Relatorio.Graphics.DrawString(string.Format("RE: ") + registro, font3_Verdana, Brushes.Black, 610, 370, new StringFormat());                                       
                                        Relatorio.Graphics.DrawString(Convert.ToDateTime(validade).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new Font("Arial black", 126), Brushes.Black, -0, topo + 565f, new StringFormat());                                         
                                        Relatorio.Graphics.DrawString(string.Format(" - ") + Sequencia, font3_Verdana, Brushes.Black, 410, 310, new StringFormat());
                                        break;
                                }
                              }

                            TOP_1 += dim_65;
                            contador = 4;
                          }                     
                           
                            ESQ_1 += dim_240;
                            dim_240 = 290f;
                            TOP_1 = 355f;
                            contador = 1;
              }
                 LinhaAtual++;

                 if (LinhaAtual <= dtgrid.NewRowIndex)
                     Relatorio.HasMorePages = true;
                 else
                     Relatorio.HasMorePages = false;   
          }               
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

Consegui o resultado que queria: depois de alguns dias...
Troquei o primeiro For por uma While e fim do do segundo For, adicionei um if:

```
                 if (cont <= pags) 
                  {
                    LinhaAtual++;
                    cont++;
                    Relatorio.HasMorePages = true;
                    break;
                   }
```

e fora do While finalizei com um outro if

```
        if (cont > pags)
          {
              Relatorio.HasMorePages = false;
              cont = 1;
              LinhaAtual = 0;              
            }
```